# Making call without confirm box in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am developing windows phone 8 app, i need to make a call to specific phone number but without call confirm dialog. Is there any way to make a call to a number without call or dont call confirm dialog?

Answer (score 1):

No, every call request generated using the API require user intervention due to security reasons.

phone call task is a Launcher and hence it has its own GUI.

> The phone call task launches the Phone application and displays the
>   phone number and display name that you specify. The phone call is not
>   placed until the user presses the call button.

[Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh394025(v=vs.105).aspx)

Comment: Is it possible to generated call request without using the phone call task API or launcher? call should be placed without user interaction.

Comment: Short answer: no, it's not possible.